# PHP AJAX Mailer Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>AJAX Contact Form Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <h1>AJAX Contact Form Demo</h1>

      <div id="form-messages"></div>

        <form id="main-contact-form" method="post" action="mailer.php">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" class="form-control" name="message" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Ajax Code:

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#main-contact-form');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');

        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Here is my Php Mailer Code:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);


$mess=
'Full Name: $name<br />
Email:  $email<br />
Comments:  $message<br /> 
';

    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  

    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    //$mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "Enter Your Email-ID For Testing"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "Your Email Password"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->Subject = "hello";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($mess);
    echo"hello";
    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("aa@gmail.com", "Bla Bla"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    $mess = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
    unset($mail);
    echo 'Successfully Sent!';

}

 ?>
```

I think there is issue in $mess keyword but i want to concatenate these prefix with the details in the sending mail .

But if i correct that also after that also the mail is not going .

Can anybody help me out why this problem is coming .

Please use the phpmailer class for this as it is required to send the mail.

Thanks For the help.

Comment: what is the value $_POST['submit']?what errors do you have?

Comment: @madalinivascu: There are no errors in this code . But mail is not going . There is some issue with Ajax because it is not calling mailer.php.

Comment: how do you know you aren't calling mailer.php?

Comment: you need not to check `isset($_POST['submit']` instead check on values  `isset($_POST["name"])` and so on...

Comment: Have you [allowed less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)? If the code is running fine, then that could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a local server like XAMPP, WAMP, LAMP. Maybe you have to configure the SMTP on your server's php.ini

If you are deploying you app in a webserver, check if your gmail account have activated the permission to allow "Less secure apps" to connect through your account.

You may use the PHPMailer Debug to track the error on the log and bring us more information about the issue:

> $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
>                          // 1 = errors and messages
>                          // 2 = messages only